# Controller Code to Loop Through Roles and Get First Letter of Role MVC 6

Tags: c#, function, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Here is my UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The line, "Roles=RolePrefixes(u.Id)" is red. I have tried everything to simply call the darn function.
In my controller, how do I call the RolePrefixes(string id) function? I say "function" because I don't know what to say.

```
  private List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
    {

      var UserManager =  _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var RoleManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var allRoles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
        //var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);
        //var usersRoles = UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        return context.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
        {
            Email = u.Email,
            UserId = u.Id,

           // THIS WORKS FOR Role Ids but not their Names::: Roles = String.Join("/", u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId.First()))


           Roles = RolePrefixes(u.Id) //THIS IS UNDERLINED IN RED.

        }).ToList();

    }


    public async Task<string> RolePrefixes(string id)
    {
        var UserManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        //var RoleManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        //var allRoles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var usersRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        string strPrefixes = "";
        foreach (var item in usersRoles)
        {
            strPrefixes += item + "/";

        }

        return strPrefixes;

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `Substring` method ? Push to  a List of strings and then call `String.Join("/",theListOfStringYouHave)` ?

Comment: I can't seem to push the "list of string" which are role names for a specific user. I can't even get the Roles for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project the role name, select the first character from the string, and join them all together.

```
return context.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
{
    Email = u.Email,
    UserId = u.Id,

    Roles = String.Join("/", context.Roles.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u2 => u2.UserId == u.Id)).Select(r => r.Name.First()))

}).ToList();
```

Comment: It sure looks good but r.Name is underlined in red and it says "IdentityUserRole<string>" does not contain a definition for the word "Name". If I type "r." the dropdown shows only UserID and RoleID for choices. I could live with it if it worked however I wouldn't learn how to call a function either.

Comment: I've fixed it to work with the default version of identity

Comment: thank you Shoe for sticking with me. However "u.Id" is underlined with red and it says: "argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'MVC6.Models.ApplicationUser'".

Comment: pasting the new line of code for Roles creates red lines under ".Select(" and "r.First()". I have "using System.Linq;" at the top of the controller and the return statement uses "context.Users.Select(u". Going crazy. This should be simpler than it is.

Comment: Me again. Spending all day trying everything I can to get a simple row with the user's roles abbreviated. This attempt-- Roles = string.Join("/", UserManager.GetRolesAsync(u))--returns this value--System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]]-- in every User row in the Roles column. No red lines but no value.

Comment: Hi, sorry I feel this is partially me :) This is what happens when you freehand code. Try changing `GetRolesAsync` to just `GetRoles`

Comment: UserManager<ApplicationUser> does not contain a definition for "GetRoles" and no extension method "GetRoles" is accepting a first arguement of type "UserManager<ApplicationUser> could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? So I went with one of your previous suggestions and substituted "r.RoleId.First" in place of "r.Name.First" and it worked, but returned the first letter of the RoleId. I wanted the Name of the role.:   Roles = String.Join("/", u.Roles.Select(r => r.Name.First()))  (there is no Name in "r." just UserId and RoleId.

Comment: Could be working off an old version of identity? `GetRoles` is here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497498%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: No. MVC 6 and what came with it.

Comment: Ah, looks like the new version doesn't have that yet. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ArgumentException: Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer'
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property) So I can get first letter of RoleId. But not name. using  Roles = String.Join("/", u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId.First()))
I think you are on the right path to helping me but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try in a slightly different direction... `_context.Roles.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u2 => u2.UserId == u.Id)).Select(r => r.Name.First())`... Personally I am waiting for a few versions into MVC6 to switch from MVC5. This is usually when the annoyances get ironed out.

Comment: Ah, Shoe. Thank you very much for sticking with this. And thanks to StackO for putting up with us.
Your last one worked, Shoe. I took the underscore off, stuck String.Join function in front and it worked and displayed just what was needed. I gotta learn this way of querying the Authentication tables. You are correct, one needs to wait 5 YEARS before using anything new from MS. I hope this helps someone else like myself. Please update your answer (not sure I can) and have a great weekend, week and more.

Comment: No problem. Early adopting a technology can be annoying :)